# how to get associated products id from checkout_cart_add acition in magneto

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

using `observer` after add to cart i am getting this

```
 Array (
     [uenc] => aHR0cDovL2NpdHl0ZWNoLmxpbnV4c2VydmVyLmNvbS9saWNodGJveC9kcm9wLWFwLXBsLTQ1Y20tNjBjbS5odG1s
     [product] => 33890
     [form_key] => kcKeJzvsx2gsdJsE
     [related_product] => 
     [super_attribute] => Array
         (
             [278] => 2707
         )

     [qty] => 1 )
```

from this how can i get simple product id which are post to add to cart

Comment: which event do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following code snippet where you want:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->load($params['product']);
if (isset($params['super_attribute'])) {
    $childProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getProductByAttributes($params['super_attribute'], $product);
}
```